# Why does the BOTTOM of my padding fail in CSS with scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

i have a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489734/css-collapsing-padding-bottom) post, but the code of the poster there is alot more complex than mine, in a way where i cant understand the solution. I see he had implemented box-sizing, where he had not before, but i already have box sizing and it doesn't work.

To reiterate, my problem is that i want a grayish shaded area over a bg image set in the html tag to fill the screen, but i want a small padding before the shaded area, so there is an outer rim of the image that is fully colored. This works TOTALLY fine so long as the content doesn't go as far as the bottom of the window. When it DOES reach the window bottom, and a scroll bar is included, the edging i've made doesn't show up... on the BOTTOM ONLY.... very annoying and confusing.

My style.css:

```
html {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    font-size: 18px;
}

body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;

padding: 8px; ##This is not preserved when the content is longer than the window, ie: scrollbar is needed. WHY?!?

-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.shade {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
padding: 8px;
min-height: 100%;

-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

//Sub-elements truncated, these shouldn't matter for this example.
```

Could someone please be so kind as to help me see what I'm doing wrong, in a way that only changes what is needed for desired effect? Thanks!

PS: If there is anything that is pointless code (doesn't do anything), please let me know as well.

Top vote for best cross-browser answer that fixes it. Trying to get a better grip on CSS. Thanks!

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/g263pff3/

Comment: Could you include the relevant HTML as well? Preferably even a fiddle.

Comment: did you try adding !important after your padding in your css?

Comment: Try using "min-height:100%;" on your body tag, instead of "height: 100%;".

Comment: @Talkingrock: This fixes the issue, at the cost of not stretching to fit the screen when the content doesnt reach the bottom of the window. Tried it, thanks.

Comment: @RachelGallen: Changing to "padding: 8px !important;" on the body does nothing in the JSFiddle, however... i looked up what !important does, and it might be part of the solution somehow.

Comment: .... tried !important on both the body and shade styles, since i figure its these two paddings that are collapsing, but this does absolutely nothing. Questioning if !important is the word for the job or not.

Comment: @ Drifter64: you're right so try this  -- Body = height:100%; padding:0px; -- div.shade =  margin: 8px;

Comment: @Talkingrock: This works, at the cost of the shade causing a scroll bar when the content does not fill the screen. You can remove ALL the box sizing with that edit and still have that glitch too.... so whatever problem that causes can no longer be fixed by box-sizing! :o

Comment: I have had BOTH of the issues above while trying to solve this, although not necessarily with the same code. If you are suggesting a solution, please make a fiddle of it if you can? This helps in two ways: 1) Makes sure the solution works. 2) Most importantly, communicates the changes needed, should they become more complicated than the above recommendations. Thank you!

Comment: That looks like a fix! Please give me a moment to compare to my version :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that fix seems to be a cheat, using a border that has the same background as the html element. Actually this will not work, as i included the color there to indicate the problem. The actual scenario is that there is an image there, so the fact that that area is CLEAR needs to be kept. You also added additional alpha coloring, possibly to help mimic the solution. Crafty work really, but i have to say respectfully that i don't think its the way to go. Prove me wrong if i am being blind of course. :)

Comment: One last thought, http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/4xpcLjt9/, it uses css only, no cheats:), and a new wrapper. Adding the backgound image caused other issues, so this may be the most robust solution so far. If it works, I'll add it as an answer. If you find another solution, please post the answer.

Comment: @Talkingrock: Now i think you see all the head banging ive been doing trying to fix this i think. Thanks for taking my criticism, and to be fair, you had no clue i was using a bg image. I've tested your solution and modified it to my needs, works flawlessly. Thank you so much for your time! My (mostly) final fiddle that will go into production: http://jsfiddle.net/4xpcLjt9/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the details on the solution (from the brainstorming comments above) that uses CSS only, no hacks, and is cross-browser compatible. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/4xpcLjt9)

The code is close to your original example, but the main changes are a new `<div class="wrapper">` that was added with `CSS display:table`, `<div class="shade">` now has `CSS display:table-cell`, and the full-screen background was added to the new wrapper.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="shade">
<div class="content">
<p>Testing content area. I certainly hope this content doesnt reach the end of the page, or my CSS will mess up. Try seeing this by resizing the window or something?</p>
<p>Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text. Filler Text.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    font-size:18px;
}
body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
}
.wrapper {
    height:100%;
    display:table;
    border-spacing:18px;
    /* can use the padding below with border-box, instead of the border-spacing
    padding:8px; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box; */
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/OaE8VAj.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom right;
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
}
div.shade {
    padding:15px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    display:table-cell;    
}
div.content {
    background-color: rgba(240,240,240,.7);
    width: 80%; 
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

---

Note: CSS Table Displays are different than HTML tables, and a few minor things to note are if an element needs to be absolutely positioned within a cell, it needs to be inside a generic "wrapper" div, and there are no column or row spans. It has great browser compatibility, http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table, except for older IE6 and IE7 and if necessary, there is a polyfill or IE Conditional Comments that can target the 2 old browsers.